# What this error is invalid context 0x0?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cgcontext, quartz-2d

I wrote the following code in ViewDidLoad

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically     from      a nib.
     -(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Veer"];

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat values[4] = {55.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}; 
CGColorRef glowColor = CGColorCreate(rgbColorspace, values); 
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetShadowWithColor( context, CGSizeMake( 5.0, 0.0 ), 20.0f, glowColor);   
[str drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10.5f, 0.5f) withFont:[UIFont      fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:100.0f]];    
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 200, 250, 100)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:50.0];
label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
[label setText:str];

[self.view addSubview:label];
  }
```

In Console I saw as

```
 Testing Clock[3286] <Error>: CGContextSetStyle: invalid context 0x0
 Testing Clock[3286] <Error>: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0
 Testing Clock[3286] <Error>: CGContextSetTextMatrix: invalid context 0x0
 Testing Clock[3286] <Error>: CGContextSetFontSize: invalid context 0x0
 Testing Clock[3286] <Error>: CGContextSetTextPosition: invalid context 0x0
 Testing Clock[3286] <Error>: CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances: invalid context 0x0
```

Comment: context 0X0 means object is initialized i.e. it is null. in your case context is null.

Comment: but what should I do to initialized it?

Comment: CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 I wrote this for context

Answer (score 4):

You should move that custom drawing code out of viewDidLoad and move it to drawRect.

You will also need to subclass the view if you want to implement your own drawRect method.

Checkout this example: http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/08/27/iphone-uiview-with-border/

Comment: Even I did, but getting same error, you try and tell me what you get,

Comment: I already mentioned that I want to do in same class, else if you will do operation every second on objects(User defined class) then it will become heavy,

Answer (score 4):

You just have to check if context exist before drawing :

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
if (context) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```