# UIImage not drawing on screen

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, uiimage

I run Xcode 4.3 and a Mac OSX 10.7.

I've been working on an app for a couple of weeks now and I'm facing a peculiar problem:-

1. I have all my assets for the app in a folder located on root.
2. I have shell scripts that take these assets and put them into a bundle during compilation.
3. I have written my own method ( similar to imageNamed: ) that takes care of image caching and have used this method universally to make all the UIImages.

The problem is that some images are not reflected in the application on the device, while all of them appear on the simulator.

I have ensured that

1. The image names are given correctly matching the names in the bundle
2. That the images are copied into the bundle (show package contents from the product app)
3. The permissions for this file are also given to (chmod 777 on the files)

Does anybody know what might be going wrong?

**UPDATE :**

I cleaned up the derived data and uninstalled the app from the simulator and launched it, now the same image does not appear on the simulator also, while the same logic and code works for all other images.

I'm facing the same problem as on the device.

Additionally i get the following errors when i enter the screen which has the image i want to draw on screen:-

```
 <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0

 <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0

 <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0

 <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0

 <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0

 <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0

 <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

Comment: Image name must same the names in the bundle, problem of case sensitivity.

Comment: I have taken care that they match!

Comment: try it Young man
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597982/what-this-error-is-invalid-context-0x0

Answer (score 3):

you can check the name of the images. it is case sensitive when you run ur build on device but works in simulator either way.

Comment: I did ensure that the names match correctly. So, there shouldn't be an issue of case sensitive or not! Although, thanks for the information!

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the extension of the image too for it to work on the device.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
```

Comment: Yes, i have done that too. Ive done this uniformly over all the images, but about 3 images do not show up on the device, while the rest do!

Comment: Double check that the extension is the same case too. There is a difference between @"test.PNG" and @"test.png".

Comment: If you are getting the image from a file you should be using     [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"test.png"]; not [UIImage imageNamed:]; this is completely wrong.